# Celery task queue is not registered

Tags: python, celery

In my code only task1-queue will be registered. Why?
`pass-params.py`

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
from celery import Celery, chain


app = FastAPI()

celery_app = Celery('tasks',
                    broker='redis://localhost:6379/0',  # broker URL
                    backend='redis://localhost:6379/1',  # backend URL
)

celery_app.conf.task_routes = {
    'celery_app.task1': {'queue': 'task1-queue'},
    'celery_app.task2': {'queue': 'task2-queue'},
    'celery_app.task3': {'queue': 'task3-queue'
    },
}


@celery_app.task(name='task1')
def task1(name):
    print(name)
    return f'Hello {name}'


@celery_app.task(name='task2')
def task2(message):
    print(message)
    return f'Previous message is: {message}'


@celery_app.task(name='task3')
def task3(name, message):
    print(f'Name: {name}       Message: {message}')
    return f'Previous message is: {message}'


t1 = celery_app.signature('task1', args=["Ehsan", ]).set(queue="task1-queue")
t2 = celery_app.signature('task2').set(queue="task2-queue")
t3 = celery_app.signature('task3').set(queue="task3-queue")
chain_of_tasks = chain(t1, t2, t3)
result = chain_of_tasks.apply_async()
```

I run celery:

```
celery -A pass-params:celery_app worker --loglevel=info
```

The output is like this:

```
 
 -------------- celery@ehsan-pc v5.2.7 (dawn-chorus)
--- ***** ----- 
-- ******* ---- Linux-5.19.0-42-generic-x86_64-with-glibc2.35 2023-05-27 15:18:55
- *** --- * --- 
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         tasks:0x7f93d17c0580
- ** ---------- .> transport:   redis://localhost:6379/0
- ** ---------- .> results:     redis://localhost:6379/1
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 4 (prefork)
-- ******* ---- .> task events: OFF (enable -E to monitor tasks in this worker)
--- ***** ----- 
 -------------- [queues]
                .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery
                .> task1-queue      exchange=task1-queue(direct) key=task1-queue

[tasks]
  . task1
  . task2
  . task3

[2023-05-27 15:18:55,433: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to redis://localhost:6379/0
[2023-05-27 15:18:55,435: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors
[2023-05-27 15:18:56,446: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: all alone
[2023-05-27 15:18:56,473: INFO/MainProcess] celery@ehsan-pc ready.
[2023-05-27 15:18:56,480: INFO/MainProcess] Task task1[113aef7c-4a28-48c8-af7a-a3e5e3cef277] received
[2023-05-27 15:18:56,483: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-2] Ehsan
[2023-05-27 15:18:56,496: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-2] Task task1[113aef7c-4a28-48c8-af7a-a3e5e3cef277] succeeded in 0.013839636027114466s: 'Hello Ehsan'
[2023-05-27 15:18:59,561: INFO/MainProcess] Events of group {task} enabled by remote.
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Please elaborate on your question. What is happening? What do you expect it to happen?

Comment: @drum I expect to see 3 queues instead of just one queue in the output